# Query's objects return null after SELECT and JOIN

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I had few tables (a,b,c and d). I tried to join all the tables to get entire data. When I tried to select all and join all the tables. My "id" and "foreign_key" return null.

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEB.menu_id = TABLEA.id
LEFT JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEC.menu_id = TABLEA.id
LEFT JOIN TABLED ON TABLED.id = TABLEA.user_id
```

**Result**

```
{
  id: null,
  user_id: null,
  others: other_data
  ...
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
  id: XXX,
  user_id: YYY,
  others: other_data
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happing because you are not mentioning which column to return. I think this will resolve your issue as-

```
SELECT TABLEA.col1, TABLEB.col2 FROM TABLEA 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEB.menu_id = TABLEA.id
LEFT JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEC.menu_id = TABLEA.id
LEFT JOIN TABLED ON TABLED.id = TABLEA.user_id
```